# Python Pandas TypeError when using .iat

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

When creating a DataFrame with two columns with same column name, using `.iat[i,j]` will result in TypeError.
Switching to `.iloc[i,j]` will solve the problem however.
Why would `iat` behave differently compared to `iloc` under such situation?

python version: 3.6.1
pandas version: 0.20.1

```
import pandas as pd
x = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],columns=['a','b','a'])
x.iloc[1,1] # works fine
x.iat[1,1]  # TypeError
```

> TypeError: len() of unsized object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that when the column names are not unique, which is your case you run into this function that acts as an indexer :

```
def _iget_item_cache(self, item):
    """Return the cached item, item represents a positional indexer."""
    ax = self._info_axis
    if ax.is_unique:
        lower = self._get_item_cache(ax[item])
    else:
        lower = self._take(item, axis=self._info_axis_number,
                           convert=True)
    return lower
```

since `ax.is_unique`is False a call is made to `self._take`, problem is this function calls `maybe_convert_indices`which expects an array but only gets an `int` and the program crashes because `mask = indices < 0` is a bool and does not have `.any()` method

**Two solutions:**
**The good:**
**Avoid same named columns**, your program runs fine with `x = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],columns=['a','b','c'])`

**The ugly:**
Modify pands source and change
`lower = self._take(item, axis=self._info_axis_number, convert=True)`
with
`lower = self._take([item], axis=self._info_axis_number, convert=True)`

PS:
Same problem will arise if you use `x.at[1,'b']` with columns have same name.